# How much time is too much time playing educational computer games?

Tags: toddler, education, video-games, screen-time, limits

I recently bought an iPad primarily for my 3-year-old daughter. I put nothing on it but educational apps and children's books. No YouTube, no Internet, no (non-educational) games. I've decided to let her use it as much as she wants, for now, and see how it goes. That was a few weeks ago.

So far she's been using the iPad maybe 2 to 5 hours each day. She still enjoys other activities -- playing outside, playing with dolls and blocks, interacting with friends, being read to, etc. And I think she might be learning a thing or two from the apps. Still, several hours a day seems like a lot. How do I know if it's too much?

I've searched the web, and there's lots of info on limiting TV time and video games, but I can't find any recommendations on limiting use if it's only educational games.

Relevant: [Should I let my 3 year old play educational games on my iPhone?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/244/should-i-let-my-3-year-old-play-educational-games-on-my-iphone)

Comment: The recommendations aren't based on the type of content but rather the type of activity. In other words, the issue is the activity...not the content.

Comment: When you say "the" recommendations, whose are you referring to? And surely the content is important... Isn't an hour spent playing an educational video game better than an hour spent with the Super Mario Brothers?

Comment: The recommendations are most of them...so when you see a study/recommendation about how long to watch TV, for example, it's about the how long it's OK to stare at a screen while sitting on a couch. Whether it's Sesame Street or Spongebob is somewhat irrelevant. Another example: Baby Einstein videos...it's been shown that they are no worse nor no better than any other television. Showing a kid that is as bad/good for them as showing them MTV.

Comment: Have you considered this from a standpoint not of trying to eliminate time spent doing something the kids enjoy, but rather how to get them to spend time on other things they enjoy too in addition to just the ipad? I don't see how the former is useful in and of itself.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments.  That's what [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting) is for.

Comment: Educational apps are scam. Nothing is better for a toddler, nothing would make shim learn more than playing in the real world. Toddlers don't need to learn stuff, but motor and cognitive habilities related to spatial 3d real eorld.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The American Association of Pediatrics suggests 1-2 hours of all screen time--regardless of content.  The following link sites some of the effects it can have:  http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/children-and-tv/MY00522

Also, beginning more than 1-2 hours of screen time at age 3 makes it more difficult to limit it when they are older-as it becomes something they are used to doing for 3 hours a day (to pick a random amount of time) and don't necessarily know how or want to find a way to occupy themselves after school, for instance if they get used to it.

Another study to read: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/07/100706161759.htm
Although it is done on older children, habits are formed from an early age... and continue into adulthood.  So, it is better to be wary than to find out in 3rd grade that had you done something differently it might be different now.  Also, as one of the studies cited states: model good screen habits-don't spend too much time watching TV/playing video games either... that way as they grow up, they don't expect the amount of time to increase.

I found one more link which specifically addresses tv, video games of educational varieties in toddlers (which, imho is closer to preschoolers than grade 5-but the grade 5 studies show what can happen if it continues)... http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/19/health/19babies.html
This study also says to limit it.  Note that the video industry says that a parent is the best judge... of course, they might just be biased (wanting parents $$?).

Comment: The problem with all these articles are that people who create them have no idea what kind of activities are available. They are focusing mostly on non-interactive  activities - watching - because this is how they'd use a tablet, or they watch TV every evening. Also they are old - 2011 is like century for smartphones and you have a bunch of great apps for your kids to develop their skills. You just have to choose appropriate one. I would never allow my kid to watch TV all day, but I think playing with phone interactively may be beneficial.

Comment: @waste it depends on the alternatives. Playing educational apps is likely not worse than reading alone in their room. But if the alternative could be creative play outside with a parent - that could be a lot better. So the question is not only "is it harmful" but "is it worse than the alternatives which are available" - and this will vary a lot depending on the environment of the child. For some the apps may well be the best available option.

Answer (score 10):

I thought I'd expand my comment into an answer:

Whether or not media is considered educational is a bit of a red herring. If a kid is going to watch TV or play a game, yes, it might as well be educational, but the fact that it is educational isn't going to change whether or not it's a good idea to be doing that activity for extended periods of time.

The concern is that you don't want to assume "It's OK" because it's educational. 5 hours of education TV is as good/bad for a child as 5 hours of Nickelodeon. It's the activity (or, with TV, the lack thereof) that is the concern. Sitting for 5 hours doing a passive activity is the concern...not specifically what they are watching.

To be fair, video games aren't the same as TV. As they aren't mentally passive. They are typically physically passive, but at least the brain is firing synapses when playing a video game.

I can't tell you how many hours a 3 year old should play on an iPad. I'd personally keep it to an hour a day at most, but that's just based on my personal opinion. And there are plenty of media options on an iPad that I think one could argue are not exactly the same thing as video game...such as ebooks or music, so it's a complicated device to form an analysis on, IMHO.

My main point, though, is just don't assume it's all OK just because the games are labeled 'educational'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but without any citations, I can't accept your claims that content is irrelevant. A quick Google search reveals studies showing that educational TV has demonstrable benefits (http://www.nytimes.com/1995/05/31/us/study-finds-educational-tv-lends-preschoolers-even-greater-advantages.html). Also, my question was about educational games, not TV. As long as the games truly are educational (and not just labeled as such), and the child is getting exercise and other forms of activity, I don't see why a one-hour limit is needed.

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't benefits to learning, but that's a different topic than "how much time should a child be doing activity X". I agree that there is a difference between TV and games, but the point remains the same. Violent shooting games have shown to improve skillsets just as learning the alphabet learning games do. The concerns of it being 'bad' for a child is less to do with the content, more to do with the type of activity (in this case, video games). As for 1-hour limit, as I stated, that's purely my own personal opinion not based on any particular science.

Comment: Regarding the study you linked to, note that it is comparing two types of TV, not how much TV is too much. A half hour of Sesame is better than a half hour of TMNT or the like. But the question is really are 4 hours of Sesame street better than a half hour?

Comment: So you say you shouldn't send your child to school either? After all, that's "physically inactive" as well, for at least 4 hours per day, probably more.

Comment: @JopV. I'm saying nothing of the sort.

Comment: @DA01 You said that just because it's educational, it doesn't mean it's good, because it's not "physically active". You did not say why this would not apply to school. So if that's not what you wanted to say, you should clarify your answer.

Comment: @JopV. context matters. A statement typically is referring to the discussion at hand, not every other possible scenario one can imagine. Since we're talking screen time, one should be able to surmise that the context I was referring to was...*screen time*. Meaning educational vs. non-educational *screen time*. We weren't talking about the school system at all. No idea why you felt that had to be brought into the conversation. But, regardless, to clarify, we're not talking about school at all. That is not in any way related to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that once you get past a certain point, content is irrelevant and that 5 hours of edu games has less to do with the content and everything to do with the lack of varied activity for a 3 yr old. i think even 2 hrs at a crack is too long, and i'm a pretty big tech advocate.

Now here's something that hasn't been mentioned... I'll bet that if she's played these games that much, that she's no longer playing the game, but has memorized the patterns. I'll bet the games are stale and she's just going thru the motions anymore. You'll be able to tell by watching her for just a couple of minutes whether or not this is the case.

From the range that you've given, i would recommend that you develop a daily routine of some sort, and slide it in there for an 60-90, 1-2x/day.

Answer (score 5):

Toddlers should not spend much time behind a screen. IMHO the use of media is far more relevant than the content of the media, particularly if the time is quite limited. The very *most* I would consider is an hour a day, and I would not let it be at one sitting.

> I've searched the web, and there's lots of info on limiting TV time and video games, but 
>   I can't find any recommendations on limiting use if it's only educational games.

That should tell you something. The difference between "educational" media and regular media is marginal compared to the difference between real life and any media.

I'm not recommending that you let your toddler spend even 5 minutes a day on Grand Theft Auto, but don't rationalize multiple hours a day with the electronic baby sitter because the content is "educational."

Get the kid a puppy. Find a good playground. Find other kids his age and have play dates. Get [Lincoln Logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Logs) or [Knex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knex). [Read to your kid](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/2669/1004). Get dolls or action figures. You get the point ... you want active rather than passive amusement.

Comment: Just a question, why is Knex a significantly higher quality tool for learning creativity than Minecraft? Why is a GI Joe a better tool for storytelling than a Lego game? Why is a game considered passive amusement, when they literally don't work without active engagement?

Comment: I have no idea whether Minecraft is or is not more effective in the abstract. My issue is that the kid interact with actual objects and/or people rather than with the screen. They will have plenty of time behind the screen when they are adults and work for a living.

Answer (score 5):

The Mayo Clinic says [too much screen time is too much screen time](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/childrens-health/in-depth/children-and-tv/art-20047952), regardless of the device, the content, or the level of interaction.

Our household has a "scale" of electronics time, depending on age. As the kid gets older, their time limits are tied somewhat to responsibilities -- they do their chores to earn additional time (privilege). There is also usage associated with homework (our elementary and middle schools have Chromebooks for each students, and often assignments must be done online), which we treat separately from their free time (which is always, so far, spent on games with little or no educational value, by their own choice).

Every single one of them thinks that my restrictions are terribly unfair and prevent them from ANY FUN AT ALL. They talk about their friends who have Kindle Fires and laptops in their room and can play as much as they want (which, since I know many of their parents, I highly doubt). They sneak the tablet or laptop into their own room to play. They throw tantrums, they whine, they beg, they attempt bribery. My daughter recently cited insufficient technology time as the primary cause of her moodiness ("it's not because I'm a tween, it's because I don't get to play computer games for hours").

BUT, **if I *let them*, my kids play on the tablet for hours at a stretch** and only stop once they get very hungry and/or tired. They even take it into the bathroom. They watch over a sibling's shoulder while another child plays. Once the tablet runs out of power (or it's bedtime, or something other obligation interrupts) -- they are *incredibly* cranky and irritable. They're obviously not able to self-regulate (even the older ones), and so I'm completely satisfied with the rules we've established.

Comment: To be fair, without any extra information, I would agree that limiting a middle school child to only 15 minutes a day of electronics time is sort of ridiculous. In addition, if you are allowing them to watch TV apart from those 15 minutes a day, I would argue you're setting a double standard based purely on personal interest, since generally, studies seem to show more negative effects of television, than of other, interactive forms of electronic media.

Comment: We tend to watch TV as a family (and talk about the shows, so it's more interactive and social than immersive), or shows they watch independently count as electronics time (she can earn extra time to get about an hour). Most weeknights, between homework, activities, dinner, and chores, there really isn't significant "spare" time to be had _anyway_ and she spends a lot of it reading.

Comment: Restricting children, especially as old as middle schoolers at all on screen time can be negative to their motivation to pursue tech fields. For example, programmers typically need to spend at least several hours per day online, and their motivation is stifled by restriction. Also, general knowledge/news can only be obtained from the internet: podcasts, blogs, videos, and articles on subjects of interest in addition to educational websites can be very beneficial.

Comment: She's actually explicitly allowed to (and often does) claim Scratch and Codecademy as "homework". Would love to see research about screen time influence on tech choices; perhaps consider another Question for that?

Comment: @bjb568 you're so right. I was always getting restricted to a _very_ limited time, and if it wasn't for my insistence and my parents not having nerves to fight with me, I wouldn't be a reverse engineer now. I strongly believe that if the child is smart enough to learn technology and not simply lose time with activities like e.g. chatting (which is a perfectly fine social activity, as long as it's not the **only** one), he/she should spend as much time as allowed by the body.

Comment: My 2 year old might spend 15 minutes fumbling around on the iPad before she finds something she wants to play. For 2 years old, she has a certain mastery of touch based devices that probably wouldn't have been learned if she was restricted to 20 some minutes a day. I have no problems letting them have it as long as they want, so long as they put it down when it's time to do anything else. Typically it isn't more than 30 or so minutes at a time before they put it down themselves and run off to play. Mine, at least. I think we desensitized them to the wow factor of the device

Comment: Anybody interested in discussion and research on appropriate electronics usage for middle school students should probably go to http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/how-should-screen-time-be-treated-to-balance-the-pro-of-education-resources-on-t -- I really regret mentioning it here, in retrospect, because I think it's highly distracting from what the OP really wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen anybody ask how much time is too much time spent reading, drawing, putting together puzzles, or playing board games. Yet as I see it, reading on a tablet is just like reading a book whose pages can never get ripped; drawing on a tablet is like fingerpainting that my daughter can do no matter what she is wearing; playing puzzles on a tablet is like putting together puzzles without the ability to lose pieces or mix them up with those of other puzzles; playing a game on a tablet is just like playing a real game but without having to worry about remembering the rules or keeping the pieces out of the baby's reach.

As for television, I'm OK with reasonably educational shows. If your child has to sit in a chair listening to talking for 5 hours a day, does it matter if it's in a school listening to a teacher versus in your living room listening to the TV? Of course "school" for toddlers
is generally a lot more engaging than the lecture-style classes of older kids, but it's generally not as educational either.

I prefer human interaction to watching TV, but there's no way I can compete educationally. For example, I can tell my daughter "Remember, look both ways before crossing the street!", but on TV they can write a catchy song, choreograph a dance, make a skit with props and dialog, and then repeat it 10 times a day all month long.

I don't like plopping my kids in front of the TV all day, but other people in their lives do and honestly, I can't say that it seems detrimental to their mental development. When my 2-year-old starts leading an imaginary marching band, talking like a pirate, holding a toilet paper tube up to her eye and calling it a "spyglass", or saying something in Spanish, I know it's because she learned it on TV. There's just no way I would even think to teach her all that stuff.

Comment: I think you are missing a lot here. Drawing on a tablet is like fingerpainting that doesn't involve learning about real materials, mixing colors, cleaning up after oneself, trying out what different objects can be used to paint with, the tactile experience of putting one's hands in a gooey substance, creating a physical object, understanding what not to do to avoid the paper ripping or the paint spilling... Similarly a child doing a puzzle on a tablet is (with the games I know) not rotating the pieces or turning them over, not having to judge exactly how precisely and how hard to place them...

Comment: @jwg: Nobody said they're equivalent; I was just pointing out that there are benefits rather than just drawbacks. Actual fingerpainting is a rare treat because it consumes paint (and paper), requires constant supervision, and entails lots of cleanup. Actual jigsaw puzzles last about 10 minutes in my house before pieces get lost or eaten. These are activities my kids would get to do a few times a year if done in real life, while they can do them for eight hours a day on a tablet.

Comment: That's a bit like saying "If I tried to go out and meet a partner I would only meet a couple of people in a year whom I liked and who liked me. By staying at home watching pornography I can enjoy sex all day every day!"

Comment: @jwg: To keep things more "family friendly", let's just say that simulated activities are not as good as real activities, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use the simulator as much as you want. Does anybody think that pilots should limit their time on a flight simulator because it's not as good as flying a real jet?

Comment: does anyone think that watching pornography all the time won't be detrimental to getting a real boyfriend or girlfriend?

Comment: @jwg: Yes -- probably most of the Internet. Surely the massive increase of availability of porn that came with the popularity of the Internet would have caused a world-wide crisis if there was any non-negligible detriment.

Answer (score 4):

The world is changing.  I think the advice on how much is too much is outdated.  Screen time isn't what it used to be.  I have a feeling my two year old will type his name before he writes it.  I think he will learn to use a mouse or a touch screen before crayons.  Even Leapfrog toys are having a hard time competing with IPads.  An IPad is more engaging and interactive than listening to a musical toy or a stuffed dog that sings and dances.  While there is nothing that compares to a wooden puzzle and a real book, I don't think there is anything wrong with a toddler growing up in the very real and changing technological world.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right to be concerned?

I would say yes, most definitely. Kids can easily become lost in games for hours on end (I should know, I was one of them). I think my parents were thankful they had something to keep me occupied while they did.. whatever it was that they did while I was in my room. It was also something they could take away from me when I was in trouble.

> I'm wondering what time periods parents are seeing their kids using ipads for??

Our daughter (almost 6 years old) gets about an hour block of screen time. With your youngest, I'd say that should be supervised time. This gives you the chance to interact and ask/answer questions. If you're looking for unsupervised time, I would recommend no more than 30 minutes. That's a decent enough time frame for you to accomplish whatever task (hopefully :) ) that you need to get done.

Establish the rules up front! Kiddos love structure (mine almost to a fault!) and will abide by the rules if you are consistent following through. We will say "You have 30 minutes until dinner is ready." On the weekends when outside play is out of the question, we'll ask her "Can you play on the computer while we clean the house? Then we can play something with you." This gives her something else to look forward to while not getting too hooked on the computer.

Comment: Definitely establish consistency and rules. It's a lot harder to complain about computer time ending when you don't have any reason to expect more. Not to say this will _eliminate_ whining and begging, but it should keep it at a tolerable level :)

Answer (score 3):

Screen time is something that should be limited for all children; at 0-2, it should be minimal or zero, as it does not support brain development in the same way that other kinds of (active) play do.  It's similar to how you might learn a school subject.

> Method 1: Listen to a lecture, with an overhead/projector showing some
>   slides.
>
> Method 2: Listen to a shorter lecture, then answer questions about the subject
>   afterwards.
>
> Method 3: Listen to a still shorter lecture, answer a few questions, and then
>   practice the activity for the same amount of time or more.

I think it would be easy to agree that method 3 is the best way to learn a new concept (listen, repeat, do).  That's because just listening (and watching - anything passive) doesn't engage the brain in the same way that actively participating does.  Completely cooperative learning is even better: you retain the memory of how to do things better.

The same applies to your child.  They're learning how to do things (physical, mental, speech, etc.), and they learn best by *doing*.  Passive content (like TV or videos on an iPad) are the worst way to do that; active content on an iPad is better, but it only can teach a limited set of skills, and unless your child is old enough to type isn't engaging them in conversation certainly.  They need to be learning multiple things at once as much as possible - speech, vocabulary/grammar, emotional/social skills, motor skills.  It's hard to get that from a screen; and this doesn't change as they get older (at least until a *lot* older).  I would suggest that 2,3,6 year olds should all have the same amount of screen time per day, and so does the [AAP](http://www.aap.org/en-us/advocacy-and-policy/aap-health-initiatives/Pages/Media-and-Children.aspx): 1 to 2 hours per day (or less).

We have two children - almost 2 and 3.5 - and while we can't completely eliminate the almost-2 year old's screen time, we limit it to very little, probably an hour or two per week, and typically only when the older one is having screen time on the television.

For the older one, we allow no more than an hour a day, and do this largely on the iPad (which is his preference).  He has 20 to 30 minutes up to twice a day (Before school and after dinner).  We encourage him to use it on the toilet for one of those periods, initially as an incentive to try to poop when he was having trouble, but now as a way to allow him to be alone without his younger brother bothering him (they share a room, so it's very hard to get this alone time otherwise).  He's responsible for setting a timer (we showed him how to use the iPad timer) and stopping when the timer goes off.  He's not all that well behaved about stopping, but that's always difficult for children that age, and a good opportunity to work on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think with any media product, its important to set up some boundaries as far as usage goes.  IMHO, educational games would get a little more leeway, but still should have boundaries. Its a good opportunity to set some good habits for your child, let her start to learn the importance of self governing or at least, that limits do exist.  This lesson can be extrapolated to many different things, TV, internet access, XBOX, Iphone etc etc.

Decide what is a good limit and apply that in a firm, loving consistent manner.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if your 3-year-old daughter will play with real toys like dolls or bricks more time than with iPad. She has to develop her cognitive ability, logic and knowledge about real world.

> So far she's been using the iPad maybe 2 to 5 hours each day.

It is too much. 1 hour a day would be enough.

> there's lots of info on limiting TV time and video games

iPad is almost the same as video game.

Also read book: “Kindergarten Is Too Late” by Masaru Ibuka

Answer (score 1):

Back in my times I was out 24/7 and when I got back home I was too tired and went to bed... I don't even remember eating food, hell all I remember is hide and seek, tag and all other fun stuff we did back in my time!

Ipad? Kids? That is a bad combination, have them go out more often. It's more healthy for them to be fighting each other than to play on their IPads.
The more time they spend on their Ipads and computers the more attached they become and the more physical activity they will miss out on.

Bottom line, it's a health issue and honestly, I grew up without a computer, didn't get into computers until I was 14ish. Played games 24/7 and I regret it, if you want your kids to thank you when they grow up and wisen up, you will make them go out more often. Not having an Ipad doesn't kill anybody, having one on the other hand is a risk.

Comment: Good answer, but do you think that if you had a computer in the house when you were younger, you might have been able to control your gaming better when you were a teenager?

Comment: Do you have any information on the specific risks or timeframes? You didn't actually address the question of "How much time is too much...?"

Answer (score 0):

I know technology is a great way to get some space from the children to get on with things, however we have a strict rule about no-(screen)-technology with our children (6 and 3). It's labor-intensive parenting, that's for sure, no computers, TV etc. I believe that use of media does not impact their developing brains in the way that personal connection, nature, art etc. does. If you try to lessen the time your younger child spends on the i-pad, you will have to be creative to make sure s/he doesn't feel deprived (seeing no limits for the older child), and think of fun alternatives. Try puzzles, musical instruments, audio books on CDs, painting etc.