# Mental effect of playing games and watching videos on mobile phones

Tags: video-games, mental-health, screen-time

My 3 years old kid plays games and visits YouTube for kids app on the mobile phone frequently. After some time some effort must be made to remove it from her. It seems like she is addicted to the phone.

Apart from the personal experience, people around me also complain that using phone to play games and watch videos affects kids' mental health.

What are the mental consequences using a mobile phone or tab to teach kids using video games or YouTube videos?

Comment: See also: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/4818/9327. Look to the right of the screen under "Related" to find more. Thanks.

Comment: This is an example of a thread that could be tagged with [screen-time], see https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1362/

Answer (score 0):

They have the same effect on children as they have on adults. They cause the subject to become addicted and lead him to prioritize his time on the phone at the expense of ignoring the people and things in the real world.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This site seeks answers that explain "why" something is good or bad. (The help section on answers explains some of this.) There is a **lot** of literature about the effect of screen time on children. This would be a far better answer if it were supported by any of the abundant literature on the subject. Please consider supporting your opinion with some evidence.

Answer (score 0):

As the person above said, it has the same effect on both children and adults. There is no true answer to what lots of screen time will do, it varies from person to person. However, you should make your child go on "breaks" from screen time, for a few hours at a time, and maybe take trips to local places like a park or playground.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This site seeks answers that explain "why" something is good or bad. (The help section on answers explains some of this.) There is a **lot** of literature about the effect of screen time on children. This would be a far better answer if it were supported by any of the abundant literature on the subject. Please consider supporting your opinion with some evidence.